# What are the elements (Mahābhūta) references in the Sarvastivada Satipaṭṭhāna?

Tags: history, vipassana, sutras, satipatthana

According to [Satipatthana Mula (By Sujato Bhikkhu edited by Piya Tan)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/13.4-Satipatthana-Mula-m10-sujato.pdf) Dharmaskandha references 6 elements that the traditional [4 elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C5%ABta) in Theravada. They are not explicitly mentioned in the text. What are these elements? What are the citation for this in English? Does this coincide with the 6 elements in the Theravada Abhidhamma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there're English versions out there. Anyway, Chapter 9 of the Dharmaskandha's Chinese version, the Foundations of Mindfulness, refers to the same Mahabhuta as the Pali version: earth, water, fire, wind, space, and consciousness. ("唯有種種地界水界火界風界空界識界。如是思惟諸界相時。")